# My fuel gauge is not reading my fuel level accurately

Tags: chevrolet, fuel-system, suburban

1998 suburban c1500
replaced fuel gauge with a known working gauge, installed a new fuel pump assembly.
when you turn the key on the gauge jumps like normal and truck runs great

what can i check next?

Comment: Did you check the wiring from the sender to the gauge?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Please edit your question and describe how the gauge isn't reading your fuel level accurately.

Comment: Does the fuel pump assembly include the sender ?